# Known message and output

Tags: nlp-question-answering

If the user knows the output from multiple digestions with a different message. Is that able to be so that the user can get the secret?

Example: Can the user find the unknown secret by knowing the following data?

Edit: updated to make a bit more sense.

```
unknown = ??;
(unknown+"A") = "";
SHA512(unknown+"B") = "";
SHA512(unknown+"C") = "";
```

.. etc ... ( can continue indefinitely )

can the unknown variable be discovered?

Comment: SHA is not encryption, it is a digest function. And what is the "unknown" parameter. SHA has no other inputs except the message payload. Is it a salt?

Comment: Yes it is a salt I believe. I am looking at https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ under HmacSHA512

Comment: I updated it to remove the second parameter

Comment: Only way to recover `unknown` is to guess and check if the guess was correct. This is infeasible if `unknown` is sufficiently complex.

Comment: @GuyKilgour It can't be a salt, since salts are only used once.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking with the "A", "B", "C" etc being supplied that after enough results, an algorithm could be used to find the unknown, since the hashed result is known.

Answer (score 2):

No secure hash function allows recovering a valid unknown input faster than brute force, even given a set of known plaintexts and hashes. That includes SHA512.

Also, note that HMAC-SHA512 is not implemented as you're suggesting. A system of SHA512(key+data) is vulnerable to a length extension attack: Given the hash for SHA512(key+"Hi"), an attacker can compute the hash for any string with that prefix, such as SHA512(key+"Hi, I'm a hacker") without knowing the key. The HMAC construction avoids this issue.

Comment: Could you explain how a hacker would computer the hash for a string with the same prefix, even though he does not know the key? And what HMAC does to prevent this. Thanks

Comment: @GuyKilgour Those topics are covered in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) for instance. It has to do with how the hash function is constructed.

Comment: @GuyKilgour They obtain a valid HMAC for that message by any normal method - using the system, spying on existing messages, or whatever.